# Performing calculations based on multiple entries of data being fed from ViewModel

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to approach this function.
I have an SQLite database that is being handled by room, and I need to update entries in sharedpreferences based on this data. There is already a dao query setup to give entries by descending order of datetime:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM data_table ORDER BY datetime DESC")
LiveData<List<Data>> getAllData();
```

These datetimes have corresponding float entries that I have to perform cumulative calculations on based on the difference of time to the next data entry's datetime. So, for example:

```
id     datetime     float
1      dt(1)        12.0f
2      dt(2)        15.0f
2      dt(3)        13.0f
```

I would start with

```
var timeDiff = ((Duration.between(LocalDateTime.parse(dt(1)),LocalDateTime.parse(dt(2)).toMillis())/1000).toFloat()
var currentValue = [big complicated formula applied to 12.0f based on timeDiff]
```

and then I would move on to

```
currentValue = (currentValue + 15.0f)
timeDiff = ((Duration.between(LocalDateTime.parse(dt(2)),LocalDateTime.parse(dt(3)).toMillis())/1000).toFloat()
currentValue = [big complicated formula applied to previous currentValue based on timeDiff]
```

until I get to the last entry, where I store that datetime and currentValue as a sharedpreference.

I'm not really sure how to go about this though. I was thinking of using a mutable array list:

```
mDataViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DataViewModel::class.java)
var tarray: MutableList<List<Data?>?> = ArrayList()
mDataViewModel.getAllData().observe(this, Observer<List<Data>>() {
   fun onChanged(data: List<Data?>?) {
      tarray.add(data)
   }
})
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, tarray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

and then performing the calculations on the list sequentially, but it doesn't appear to be populating. I would much prefer to perform the cumulative calculations as they're fed from the database. This is my first time using SQlite though, and I'm not there is a much easier way of accomplishing this than what I'm attempting to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would much prefer to perform the cumulative calculations as they're fed from the database. This is my first time using SQlite though, and I'm not there is a much easier way of accomplishing this than what I'm attempting to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Perhaps consider the following as a pointer which may be along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish. That is getting the data you want from the database.

```
/* Create the TEST ENVIRONMENT */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, datetime TEXT, float REAL);
INSERT INTO data_table (datetime,float) VALUES('2021-04-01 12:00',12.0),('2021-04-01 13:00',15.0),('2021-04-01 16:00',13.0);
/* Show the raw/actual data */
SELECT * FROM data_table;

/* now extract the useful data */
WITH y AS (
    SELECT 
        datetime,
        float, 
        /* Get the float value of the previous row (as first would be NULL use COALESCE get the current float value )*/
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT float FROM data_table WHERE datetime < x.datetime ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1 ),x.float
        ) AS prev_float,
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT datetime FROM data_table WHERE datetime < x.datetime ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1 ),
            (SELECT datetime FROM data_table ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 1)
        ) AS prev_datetime
    FROM data_table AS x
)
SELECT datetime, prev_datetime, strftime('%s',datetime) - strftime('%s',prev_datetime) AS datediff_in_seconds, float, float-prev_float as floatdiff FROM y ORDER BY datetime ASC;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data_table; /* clean-up the testing environment */
```

So you start off with the following data as an example :-

[image]

And it produces :-

[image]

i.e. the manipulated data

- Note the use of `COALESCE` to return previous values for the first row. COALESCE returns the first non-null value of the listed values. The first being the value from the previous row, which would be null for the first row so it gets the current value

  - in the case of the date time, datetime could have been used however as cab be seen a sub query has been used just to demonstrate the flexibility of SQlite SQL.

It's then just a matter of two additional steps for Room :-

1. Create the **Dao query** using the complex query (from the `WITH ....` to the `SELECT .... FROM y ORDER BY datetime ASC;` )
2. Create a suitable **POJO** class/data class. For the example/pointer given you'd have **var**'s or **val**'s for

   1. **datetime**
   2. **prev_datetime**
   3. **datediff**
   4. **float**
   5. **prev_float**
   6. **floatdiff**

as these are the columns returned.

Comment: This is awesome, and indeed looks like the type of solution I'm looking for. I just picked up programming for android about a week ago, and this is all very new to me. 

The database is already created, if it is not already present, on initial app startup, and is handled by a DataDatabase 'asynctask class. Can this go in here, or does it have to go in a completely different class? Also, could I put the SharedPreferences edit within this class, and call it when a database edit occurs?

Comment: The POJO class would probably be a class on it's own. The Dao could be a class on it's own or in with other Dao's (if the former then you add the Dao class it to the @Database). I wouldn't put the shared prefs edit in with the POJO, however you could.

Comment: @JonathanMcGraw PS SQLite tools (DB Browser for SQLite, DBeaver and Navicat (I prefer Navicat) are useful for building/testing such queries.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really about the database or the `LiveData`, right? You just want a way to run through this set of data?

You could use `zipWithNext` to turn the data into a list of `Pair`s, and run a fold on that. You gave an example of how you'd handle the first case, and how you'd handle every case after that, but really they're all

```
currentValue = currentValue + data1's float
timeDiff = time difference between data1 and data 2
currentValue = something based on currentValue and timeDiff
```

where `currentValue` starts off as 0, so on your first run it's `currentValue = 0f + 12.0f`

[Here's how you can do that with a fold](https://pl.kotl.in/koz61Wc4j):

```
// Just a basic version of the data you're working with, as a demo
data class Thing(val time: DateTime, val number: Float)
typealias DateTime = Int

val stuff = listOf(Thing(10, 12.0f), Thing(12, 15.0f), Thing(15, 17.0f))

fun main() {
    stuff.zipWithNext().fold(0f) { currentValue, (data1, data2) ->
        val timeDiff = data2.time - data1.time
        val newValue = complicatedTask(currentValue + data1.number, timeDiff)
        newValue
    }
    .run(::println)
}

fun complicatedTask(number: Float, timeDiff: Int) = number * timeDiff

>> 117.0
```

The accumulator you're folding through is that `currentValue` float, so you start with `0f` and return the new value at the end of the fold function, and that's what pops out at the end.

---

If you want the datetime too, [you can make that part of the accumulator](https://pl.kotl.in/4tgT182m8) - I'm just gonna reuse that data class but you can make your own, or use a basic `Pair` or whatever:

```
stuff.zipWithNext().fold(Thing(0, 0f)) { (_, currentValue), (data1, data2) ->
    val timeDiff = data2.time - data1.time
    val newValue = complicatedTask(currentValue + data1.number, timeDiff)
    Thing(data1.time, newValue)
}

>> Thing(time=12, number=117.0)
```

Using a start value with `time=0` (gotta have something), and at the end of the function you're returning the first datetime, i.e. `d(1)` when you're comparing `d(1)` and `d(2)`. You could return the other one if that's what you wanted. I just gave it an anonymous `_` variable name in the function because you don't actually use it in there, you only care about it when it pops out as the result.

I'm not sure if that helps with what you're doing - if you want to keep running this process every time a new value is observed (maybe that's why you want the datetime in the result?) you could make the lambda a separate function, that way the `fold` can call it, but you can also use it yourself for one-off updates when you get some new data. And you can use that result as the start value for a new fold, if you need to run it on a bunch more values. Hope that makes sense!